# Are there any alternatives to OleDb to improve performace?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I have a ms sql 2012 server and I use this function to add/records:

```
static String conString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source = " + ecommerceServer + "; Initial Catalog = " + eCommercedbName + "; User Id = " + eCommerceUsername + "; Password = " + eCommercepassword + ";";

    public bool InsertSQL(String query, String Tablename)
    {
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(conString);
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
            int count = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            return (count > 0) ? true : false;
        }
        catch
        {
            if (conn.State.ToString() == "Open")
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

The function is quite slow (for example I have similar execution for MySQL and it workd much faster. Is there any faster ways than `OleDb` ?

Comment: Try [SqlClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.aspx). Also you want to pool your connections rather than connecting for each query.

Comment: and look into applying / wrapping yourSQLConnection around a using(){} clause

Comment: put your connection string into the app.config file. I will past an example of what your code should look like..also do not use hard coded SQL commands ...avoid SQL Injection..

Comment: Andrew this should be enough to get you started.. if you have any questions please don't hesitate to ask.. also if thing continue to run slow.. please have a look at your Query and also remember @Forcey suggestion, use connection pooling it's not good to keep on opening and closing the connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Andrew below is an example of how you could you SQL Client as well as doing Transactions in your Query.. you can use this as a guide / learning example also replace the variables to fit your current example. also notice how I am reading my connection string from the app.config file if you do not need the Transactional code you can remove it.. but I believe it's best to do things using transaction

```
 private void SomeMethod()
 {
    SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand();
    using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["strConnectionString"]))//strConnectionString
    {
       sqlConn.Open();
       sqlcmd.Connection = sqlConn;
       SqlTransaction transaction;
       // Start a local transaction.
       transaction = sqlConn.BeginTransaction("DeleteRecs");
       sqlcmd.Transaction = transaction;
       sqlcmd.CommandTimeout = 60;
       sqlcmd.CommandText = "uf_DeleteWeeks";
       sqlcmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
       try
       {
          sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
          sqlcmd.Transaction.Commit();
       }
       catch (SqlException sqle)
       {

        try
        {
           transaction.Rollback("DeleteRecs");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
       Console.WriteLine(sqle.Message);
       }
      }
      ((IDisposable)sqlcmd).Dispose();
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

If its performance you're concerned about have a look at [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx)

[Here's](https://web.archive.org/web/20210927181836/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/102109-1.aspx) an example (in VB.Net though) that will give you an idea of the speed increases involved.

Comment: He's using C#... your answer has nothing to do with what you have posted in regards to the OP's question..

Comment: @DJ KRAZE: Yes I'm aware he's using C#, thats why I mentioned it in my post. But how is my answer not relevant to the OP's qeustion? he specifically asked about improving performance. Also, the MSDN link contains C# example code so I'm not sure exactly what your point is.

Comment: Bic your example does not appear to address his issue.. maybe I am missing something here but based on his question and your response, it doesn't seem to apply to what his initial code shows..It's up to the OP to clarify what his issue(s) are so that others will not assume as well as myself.

Comment: Bic also he has InsertSQL based on his code one cannot interpret his code as being a bulk insert.. verses a single called Insert..

Comment: @DJ KRAZE: Yes that's a fair point. The mental leap I made was that in my experience a single insert statement is not going to cause performance issues. The only scenario I can think of would be massive binary dumps or similar. So I assumed that the method posted was being called multiple times. But you're right that I don't have enough information to back that up. Maybe the OP can expand on that.

Comment: @DJ KRAZE: Also, the single statement could contain a value list of thousands of rows. Then using bulk insert would help. But again, I don't have enough information.

Comment: that's correct and you see what my initial comment meant there was not enough information provided..

Comment: @DJ KRAZE: Yes I understand what you meant now. I still think though that if insert performance is bad then SqlBulkCopy is the way to go.

Comment: I agree but there are other reason as to why and insert can perform slowly or performance is poor.. SQL Server itself could be the issue, Net work Issues, Hardware Issues, Indexing issues..ect.. it's not always the code that's the problem..